# Is .NET code post JIT being executed the same as native code

Tags: c#, .net, clr, jit

.NET languages all compile to an intermediate language (*MSIL*).

As far as i know, during execution (and sometimes during other stages, which i am not fully knowledgeable about -- NGEN), code is being JITted (Compiled from *MSIL* into actual *machine code*).

I am wondering if after JITting the code there are performance "penalties" coming from the fact that the code is executing on the CLR, or whether the code behaves "the same" as any other native code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of performance differences:

1. The free store for managed objects is implemented as a stack, not a heap (except for the Large Object Heap), and is lower overhead than the heap used by most native allocators.  But then you pay for garbage collection and compaction later.
2. The JIT can inline some calls that an AOT compiler would have to leave virtual (i.e. calls into other assemblies).  But the AOT compiler can spend more time looking for optimization opportunities.
3. Theoretically, the JIT can use advanced instructions present on the particular CPU running the code (e.g. AVX).  Still waiting for a JIT that actually makes good use of them, though.
4. AOT compilers can use profiling data to control layout of code memory.  JIT compilers almost always emit functions into memory in the order they were compiled.

Comment: There's a (dated) list of some CPU-specific optimizations that the CLR makes here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2005/08/15/451845.aspx

Comment: I assume you talk about bump-pointer allocation in the first paragraph. If so, this has nothing to do with the JIT (aside from the fact that it likely inlines the fast path), both interpreters and AOT-compiled, GC'd language implementations (such as GHC) do the same thing.

Comment: @delnan: The question refers to "any other native code".  Most native code doesn't use bump-pointer.  So it's an interesting difference between .NET and native code that persists beyond the JITting process.  "garbage collected" is pretty much the de-facto meaning of "managed" anyway; the question isn't comparing the CLR to other managed frameworks, but to "native" code.

Comment: And AOT compilation is completely independent of garbage collection. Bump-pointer allocation is an interesting point when considering CLR performance versus C/C++ performance, but conflating these two issues doesn't help. We have enough people being grossly confused about language implementations as it is.

Comment: @delnan: I made multiple independent points.  That's what the paragraph breaks mean.  The paragraph about the free store makes no mention of JIT vs AOT.  Would it help if I numbered them and put horizontal rules in between?

Answer (score 1):

The main performance penalty to JITed code is the time taken to compile the code when it's first run.  That usually only exhibits itself as a (slightly, perhaps imperceptibly) longer startup time, though it can be a real hit if you're using it in a scenario like CGI where a new process is spawned to handle every request.  Not that a CGI script written in .NET is a common use case, but it's the first example that popped into my head so I'm going to run with it.

NGen can improve your startup time by skipping the JIT step.  The benefit is going to be biggest in a short-running program that gets run frequently, like a CGI script.  (Or perhaps a Windows service that's set to start automatically is a better example, now that I think of it.)  For programs that run infrequently, the executable is unlikely to be cached in memory so it's probably going to have to be loaded from the disk each time.  The time it takes to read from disk is likely to dominate startup time and overwhelm NGen's benefits.  And for programs that run for a long time, startup time probably isn't a significant performance characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

Typically code written natively will be more performant as you can use optimizations that are available to a specific architecture that you might need to know at design time, for example SSE.  There are also other things to consider for the performance of one language or another, for example Garbage Collection vs manual memory management.

As far as NGEN goes, I don't think there will be much of a performance difference between the JITTED code and what NGEN does, other than the JITTED code gets generated at runtime (which incures a performance penalty when the actual compilation happens).

Comment: My question referred to "what happens AFTER jitting": Is the CLR adding any overhead, or is it just like running native code?